# Cannot send session cache limiter - headers already sent

Tags: cookies

I searched this topic, but I didn't find an exact match to my problem. So today, when I visited my site, it shows the message below.

> Warning: session_start() [function.session-start]:
>   open(/home/content/49/8781249/html/wp-content/uploads/car-rental/sessions//sess_1r5d6a959f02404mim9mt8di65, O_RDWR) failed: File too large (27) in
>   /home/content/49/8781249/html/wp-content/themes/car-rental/system/libraries/session.php
>   on line 15
>
> Warning: session_start() [function.session-start]: Cannot send session
>   cookie - headers already sent by (output started at
>   /home/content/49/8781249/html/wp-content/themes/car-rental/system/libraries/session.php:15)
>   in
>   /home/content/49/8781249/html/wp-content/themes/car-rental/system/libraries/session.php
>   on line 15
>
> Warning: session_start() [function.session-start]: Cannot send session
>   cache limiter - headers already sent (output started at
>   /home/content/49/8781249/html/wp-content/themes/car-rental/system/libraries/session.php:15)
>   in
>   /home/content/49/8781249/html/wp-content/themes/car-rental/system/libraries/session.php
>   on line 15

Yesterday it was all fine. Also I cannot log in to my WP site.

Can anyone help me fix this?